# Difference between wasdev and openliberty maven plugin

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty, liberty-maven-plugin

What are the difference between net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins and io.openliberty.tools liberty-maven-plugin and which one should I use ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## New, preferred (3.x) version

#### io.openliberty.tools:liberty-maven-plugin

The `io.openliberty.tools` one is the newer, better version of the **liberty-maven-plugin**, and the one you'll likely want to use for new development.

## Older (2.x) version

#### net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins:liberty-maven-plugin

The older `net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins` plugin is what evolved into the newer `io.openliberty.tools` plugin.

Along with the move from version 2.x to version 3.x of the **liberty-maven-plugin**, the groupId was also changed from  `net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins` (versions 1.x-2.x) to `io.openliberty.tools` (version 3.x and beyond).

## Why use the newer plugin?

Both versions of the plugins can be used to work with (install, deploy to, etc.) either Open Liberty or WebSphere Liberty servers.  (so that is not a concern in choosing one vs. the other).

The newer V3 plugin provides the helpful new ["dev mode"](https://www.openliberty.io/blog/2019/10/22/liberty-dev-mode.html) support.   Plus you'll find a lot more recent material using this version such as the [Open Liberty guides](https://openliberty.io/guides/).

It also enhances and streamlines some of the other goals and configuration (besides "dev mode").  There's a summary of the 3.x enhancements [here](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/releases/tag/liberty-maven-3.0).

So at this point the only reason to use the 2.x plugin from `net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins` would be to continue with a project already using this version of the plugin (unless or until you're ready to migrate).

Comment: The older version supported the "package-server" goal which seems to have been dropped in the new plugin.

Comment: The "package-server" goal was renamed to "package" in the 3.x release, as were all the "xyz-server" goals (renamed to "xyz").  There's a set of release notes describing the change here:  https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/releases/tag/liberty-maven-3.0/